# Change the layout of pie charts in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Subjects = c("Literature", "Geography", "Physics", "Arts", "Overall"),
                 Sex = rep(c("Boys", "Girls"), 5),
                 N = c(22, 17, 16, 24, 77, 20, 14, 17, 25, 78)) |>
  group_by(Subjects) |>
  mutate(pct = proportions(N) * 100) |>
  mutate_at(vars(pct), list(~ round(., 1))) |>
  ungroup()


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, color = "white") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~ fct_reorder(Subjects, N),
             ncol = 2,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct, label = paste0(pct, "%")), size = 5, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        legend.box.spacing = unit(1, "cm")) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1")
```

[image]

I want to create two graphs with the data entered.

In the first graph, the “Overall” pie chart should be positioned to the right of the four other charts, aligned between “Physics” and “Arts” (before the captions).

In the second graph, I intend to place the “Overall” pie chart in the middle of the four other charts so that the four other charts are positioned around the “Overall” chart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also nicely possible with the `patchwork` package:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame(Subjects = c("Literature", "Geography", "Physics", "Arts", "Overall"),
                 Sex = rep(c("Boys", "Girls"), 5),
                 N = c(22, 17, 16, 24, 77, 20, 14, 17, 25, 78)) |>
  group_by(Subjects) |>
  mutate(pct = proportions(N) * 100) |>
  mutate_at(vars(pct), list(~ round(., 1))) |>
  ungroup()

# creating a helper function to plot filtered df in parts

plot_parts <- function(df) {
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = Sex)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, color = "white") +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    facet_wrap(~ fct_reorder(Subjects, N),
               nrow = 2,
               strip.position = "bottom") +
    geom_text(aes(y = pct, label = paste0(pct, "%")), size = 5, 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
    theme(
      legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
      legend.spacing.y = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
      legend.box.spacing = unit(1, "cm")) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1")
}

# overall plot
go <-  df %>% 
  filter(Subjects == "Overall") %>%
  plot_parts()

# The four subjects
g4 <- df %>% 
  filter(Subjects != "Overall") %>%
  plot_parts()

# Subjects for the left
gl <- df %>% 
  filter(Subjects %in% c("Geography", "Literature")) %>%
  plot_parts()

# Subjects for the right
gr <- df %>% 
  filter(Subjects %in% c("Physics", "Arts")) %>%
  plot_parts()

# Patchwork 'patches' them together in order (sizes malleable)
g4 + go + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

```r
gl + go + gr + plot_layout(guides = "collect", widths = c(4, 3, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: That is pretty cool, never used this package before, are you able to control the size of plots too? Is that what the width does in this last one?

Comment: Wow. That's really cool. Thank you, @Andy Baxter!

Comment: @sconfluentus a little trickier to control plot size as they'll resize relative to the column widths/relative heights. But mostly intuitive to use which I like!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gridExtra` to arrange plots and create named charts in a variety of ways with each named or numbered. You seem capable of that part. To place them as you like

To diplay them in a row with the original first:

```
 require(gridExtra)
 placement<-c(Overall, Literature, Geography, Physics, Arts) #your individual plot names
 grid.arrange(grobs = placement, ncol = 5) ## display plot
```

The key to this is to set the columns to how ever you many want in a row and decide which plot goes where.

For the one with it in the middle, you can change the order:

```
 placement<-c( Literature, Geography, Overall,Physics, Arts)
```

If you want it in the middle of a rectangle in a star shaped pattern then you have a more complicated problem, but you can test `ncol=` to create a grid and place the plots in different cells until you get what you want

[Here is a link to the `gridExtra` pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf)

Also, you can use `NA` in your code to help leave gaps. The following code should create 3 columns,3 rows with the four topics in the corners and the Overall in the center of the middle:

```
     placement<-c(Literature, NA,Geography,
                     NA, Overall,NA ,
                     Physics, NA,  Arts) #your individual plot names with spaces in grid
     grid.arrange(grobs = placement, ncol = 3) ## display plot
```

Here is more information about working with `gridExtra` and facet wrapping to create beautiful placements

Comment: Hi @sconfluentus. I am running into the following error: Error in `gtable_add_grob()`:
! `grobs` must be a single grob or a list of grobs, not a character vector.

Comment: I have updated gridExtra and tried grid.arrange(grobs = list(placement), ncol = 3), but it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try eliminating the QUOTE MARKS (my bad) it took that as a string thing, but it should be the variable name. Sorry about that~